# SQL where x like variable

Tags: sql, android-room

I'm looking for a way to use a variable inside a where like clause in sql, something like this:
`select * from Party where participants like '%:id%'`
I know you can fix this using transact sql like this:
`select * from Party where CHARINDEX(:id, participants) > 0`
but I don't know if `Room` (android database) supports transact sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `||` syntax will work sqlite and oracle db's. You can assign and use id or other variable.

```
select *
from Party
where participants like '%' || id || '%';
```

Comment: So this || operator will chain together the % to basically become: %value%?

Comment: yes, you can use it on select or any other place. Its use is very common.